# Wrong Facebook OpenGraph title. Is this editable?

Tags: facebook, metadata, facebook-opengraph

Unfortunately we had a mistake in our title tag (double title tag) and Facebook made the OpenGraph with it. Of course we changed our html and is now OK, but not the graph.

**Is there any way we may change it?**

**The title in graph is:** `<title>Home | El Vestidor</title>`
**And should be:** `Home | El Vestidor`

**Please take a look at:** https://graph.facebook.com/265387210196404

Thanks!

Comment: "Home | El Vestidor" and "Home | El Vestidor" are the same.

Comment: @daknøk The difference is that the current version is surrounded by `<title>` tags and shouldn't be (see the link). I've edited the question appropriately, but the change is still pending peer review, as I don't have the 2000 reputation that the editing questions requires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 95 likes. I believe Facebook will lock in the title after 50 likes.  The price you pay for being liked so much.  Sorry.

See "**Edit Meta Tags**" section of 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

Comment: So, there is nothing I can do? The url will be wrong for ever? Is there a way to delete the graph and start again?

Comment: Try contacting Facebook directly.  Maybe they have something that might help.

Answer (score 0):

If you update the metadata in your page, then go visit the [Facebook OpenGraph Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), it should both show you what Facebook sees from your URL and simultaneously clear their cache.

This should fix your problem.